# AngularJS : md-virtual-repeat-container in Angular2 or above

Tags: angular, typescript

Anybody used virtual scrolling in `Angular2` or above.

I was searching for the example in `typescript`. I am getting example with `md-virtual-repeat-container` using `Angular1`.

Can anyone please clarify how I can achieve virtual scroll in `Angular 2/4/5`

Comment: @JBPakalapati "Thanks in advance" is unnecessary noise. Please don't add it.

Answer (score 1):

I use this library to do then https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll